# Determine Size Of Array of Equal Items Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, array-formulas, frequency, flatten

I have an array that looks like this

`11100100110`

essentially, an array of fixed size with each item being a 1 or 0 with the last item always equal to 0.

Consider each set of consecutive 1's to be a "bucket". I'd like a formula to determine the size of each bucket. So the output of this formula for the above sequence should be

`312`

as an array. Ideally this works in both excel and google sheets.

If you are interested this is the result of a list of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) configurations where the 0's in my sequence represent bars and the 1's represent stars (the final value is a dummy 0 to make things easier to work with). I want the size of each non-empty bucket in a given configuration of stars and bars.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: @TheMaster I wonder if it's wise to spread this paranoia of email exposure... it's like saying: "if you go out for a walk you may die in a random car accident". well, both may be true but common...

Comment: @player0 Disagree. In fact I could easily write a script getting the email addresses of all those who have ever shared a spreadsheet here for the last 4 years or so. It's not uncommon as you believe.  I wish to spread awareness until Google changes it's configuration, but  also as a side effect, to get well  good described questions that don't rely on external links.

Comment: @player0 I mean... it is clearly a pitfall. I wouldn't share a sheet from my real email address. The metaphor doesn't really hold up. The negative side effect will happen with 100% certainty in this case. The only question is how badly that might affect you. More akin to saying "if you get very drunk, you will have a bad hangover". Most people know this, but still worth telling the uninformed teenager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the standard method with Frequency which will work with Excel 365 and GS:

```
=FILTER(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A11=1,ROW(A1:A11)),IF(A1:A11=0,ROW(A1:A11))),FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A11=1,ROW(A1:A11)),IF(A1:A11=0,ROW(A1:A11))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX((JOIN(, LEN(SPLIT(A1, 0)))))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(1/(1/
 LEN(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(A1:K),, 9^9)), " ", ), 0))))),, 9^9)), " ", ))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `A2:A9` contains the data,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A9,ROW(A2:A9)),IF(NOT(A2:A9),ROW(A2:A9))),"where Col1>0",))
```

- `FREQUENCY(data,classes)` to get the frequency of `data` in `classes`
- Make sequence of row numbers as `data`, if `1`
- Make sequence of row numbers as `classes`, if not  `1`
- `QUERY` to get rid of zeros